# How to install scoped private npm package from Artifactory in Github Actions

Tags: github-actions, artifactory, npm-registry

This question includes a specific use-case:

1. I have a private scoped package: `@myscope/mypackage`
2. It hosted in Artifactory NPM registry: `https://company.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/npm/my-npm-registry/`
3. I need to use my credentials to consume it.
4. I want to consume it in Github Actions.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8):

### `.npmrc`

First, you need to configure your access in a local `.npmrc` file. You can put this file in your source root folder.

```
always-auth = true

# First, set a different registry URL for your scope
@myscope:registry=https://company.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/npm/my-npm-registry/
# Then, for this scope, you need to set the token
//company.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/npm/my-npm-registry/:_auth = {{your token - see below}}
```

### Token

You need to get the NPM Token from Artifactory (note it isn't your API Key.

1. Get your *Artifactory API Key* from your Artifactory profile: https://company.jfrog.io/ui/admin/artifactory/user_profile
2. Run the next command on your Linux terminal: `curl -u {{ ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME }}:{{ ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY }} https://company.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/npm/auth/`

   - Powershell:

     ```
     $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f {{ ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME }},{{ ARTIFACTORY_API_KEY }})))
     Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} https://company.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/npm/auth/
     ```
3. You should receive this:

   ```
   _auth = {{ YOUR_NPM_TOKEN }}
   always-auth = true
   ```
4. So now you can take this Token and put it in the `.npmrc` file above.

### Github Actions

How to do all this in Github Actions?

1. First, save your Jfrog username and API Key in Github Secrets: `JFROG_USER` & `JFROG_PAT`.
2. And you can add the next step to your workflow, **after** checkout and **before** `yarn/npm install`:

   ```yaml
   - name: npm token
     run: |
       echo "@myscope:registry=https://company.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/npm/my-npm-registry/" > .npmrc
       echo "//company.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/npm/my-npm-registry/:$(curl -u ${{ secrets.JFROG_USER }}:${{ secrets.JFROG_PAT }} https://company.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/npm/auth/)" >> .npmrc
   ```